Need to preload figma iFrames in reactjs
I'm a novice in reactjs and I have been tasked with pre-loading figma iframes to load in quicker in reactjs.
The scenario:
A nav bar on the left will control the right side of the page that will load in different figma iframes. I have that part down.
The problem is when each link is click (and right side of page loads the iframes) it takes too long (my bosses words, not me) to load.
Is there anyway I can preload all 7 figma iframes so that when each navmenu item is clicked, they don't load as they are preloaded.
I am currently pulling in each iframe as a component that will change on click.
Would really appreciate help. Thanks.
Tried everything. The functionality of clicking the navmenu works but the load speed of each figma iframe is slow.
I tried to suggest lowering the file size of each figma iframe. A no go.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
